# Help identifying the fandom easter eggs in this intro

Tags: object-identification

In the first area I guess we have some Marvel references, the second seems to be Star Wars, I have no clue what the third area is supposed to be from, with the orange/yellow area and the race track loops (*image below*).

[image: A road swirls across the sky over a yellow landscape and a purple sky]
 <sub>*Click to enlarge*</sub>

If someone could help me understand the references in this intro, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

It appears to be the '[Snake Way](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Snake_Way)' from *Dragon Ball Z*.

[image: Goku sprints down the Snake Way, a road that swirls on top of yellow clouds and below the purple sky]